# creating QR code using zbar sdk for iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mobile-website, qr-code

ZBAR sdk is normally used to read QRcode or barcode & convert it to user data. Can we use ZBAR API to create QRcode for iphone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I know Zbar SDK can only be used to read.

Maybe this link will be of some help.

[onbarcode](http://www.onbarcode.com/tutorial/iphone-barcode-generator-guide.html)

Comment: yes, you are correct. But, onbarcode is not an opensource. I need some opensource API to create QRCode in iphone & Android.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/myang-git/QR-Code-Encoder-for-Objective-C worked well to generate QR Codes even with much content and UTF-8 characters (where some other generators I tried failed). The project is active and Apache 2.0 licensed.